# Automating (Shell Script) Installation of RPM package in Suse linux 10?

Tags: shell, rpm

I am trying to write a shell script to install certain RPM Packages, but one of the package triggers a configuration window which requires user intervention. I want to automate the installation of packages. Is there any switch in rpm or any method to automate it.

Comment: What is the command line that your script currently uses for the `rpm` command?

Answer (score 0):

One of the golden rules in RPM packaging is that your installation/uninstallation NEVER, absolutely NEVER can be interactive. I wouldn't touch an RPM package that opens a config window with a 10 foot pole. If they are yours, you need to redo these RPMS. If they are not yours, I would redo them as well by providing some kind of default configuration rather than doing that config window.